# What does the Ferengi Emblem represent?

Tags: star-trek, ferengi

Looking at the official Ferengi Emblem I am at a loss as to what it is supposed to represent (other than perhaps constantly accumulating wealth).  Does anyone know what the creative staff had in mind when designing the Ferengi Emblem?

[image: The Ferengi Logo]

Comment: Looks kind of beetle-ish... and the Ferengi like their beetles

Comment: Cyclops Darth Vader

Comment: Hmmm, it is remnant of the Ferengi starship design.

Comment: If you squint at it just right it kinda looks like hands grabbing something.  Perhaps something valuable?  Since this is Ferengi culture, the small hand grabs something valuable, and then the bigger hand takes it from him?  It could just be random though.

Comment: It's a really buff looking guy putting his hands up so he don't get devoured by a beetle. The designer was rewatching Commando one day. Suddenly a thought comes to him. "Man I really hate Arnold Schwarzenegger. I hope one day he gets eaten by a beetle, because whatever." **Light bulb**

Comment: Is it an ear/lobe? From what I gathered from DS9 lobes are associated with the ability to make profit.

Comment: @HikaruIchijyo: One would have to know, when that emblem was first introduced. When the ferengi were introduced, they were ment to be a (military) advesary. That would point towards a ship. The DS9-Ferengis are greedy capitalists. That would point towards the lobe-theory.

Comment: @Einer I was just about to say it looks remarkably like a large ear.

Comment: You may wish to reconsider your acceptance in light of my finding a canon description of the emblem's meaning on an Impel card; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/73278/20774

Comment: Thanks for that @Richard.  Excellent and fully canonical answer as always ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The official Impel Star Trek Trading Card for the [Symbol of the Ferengi Alliance](http://www.comiccollectorlive.com/LiveData/SaleItem.aspx?id=102e2ac0-e5d6-4e80-bf84-27266d7a4d34) contains the following information on its reverse:

> The behavior of the Ferengi Alliance and its race can often seem
>   sinister or underhanded. Actually, the Ferengi follow their own very
>   strict code of ethics. They seem so aggressive because they are the
>   galaxy's most extreme capitalists -- they seek to acquire as much
>   property and profit as they can in life. Conquest in trade or business
>   is as important to the Ferengi as victory in combat (if not more so).
>
> **The Symbol of the Ferengi Alliance is a graphic representation of their narrow view of life: a "dog-eat-dog" world is represented by a
>   small circle being engulfed by a larger symbol, which itself is being
>   "eaten" by another!**

[image]

Comment: Hah, I knew it! The moment I saw it I was like "it's a hand grabbing a coin but being devoured by a bigger hand!"

Answer (score 3):

I think any answer to this would be subjective. There's no specific answer because it was designed by Michael Okuda as something to represent rank. No further thought was behind it in official canon. Nothing official is mentioned about the logo on the official ST site article.

Quote from Memory Alpha (and I'm not claiming this to be the ultimate truth):

> The logo and tattoo was designed by Michael Okuda. According to production work from the first season of TNG, no chevron indicated a regular crewmember, one chevron indicated a salesman, third class; two chevrons were worn by salesmen, second class and three chevrons (the third one wider than the regular two) would have indicated a salesman, first class, similar to an assistant manager. The last version of the tattoo was never seen on the show. The first civilian (and therefore untattooed) Ferengi seen was Omag. All the Ferengi seen on DS9 were civilians and none of them wore tattoos."

Answer (score 3):

I cannot find any sources to hand, but from back in the 1990s I recall a behind-the-scenes documentary mentioning that it represented the 'dog eat dog' nature of Ferengi society.

The 'little' dog has acquired a pearl but has now been consumed, with its wealth, by the bigger dog.

Though presumably the Ferengi wouldn't have *dogs* as such, but something analogous.

Comment: You could turn this from a good answer into a great one by locating a source.

Answer (score 0):

I would add my own interpretation. the statements regarding a dog eat dog nature is very true. however i would also postulate that it is a simple graphic representation of the great flowing river of commerce. you can be lucky, and grab fortune on the river, but you are still flowing within it. you are meant to navigate it and carry goods from supply to demand, perhaps the small ball is being carried in the hands of the larger object, while flowing on the river of the larger object.

Comment: I thought of fish. Small fish eaten by Bigger Fish...